# Bug in R for round or / function?

Tags: r

Try this code:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
[...]

> round(55.8/1.8)
[1] 31
> 55.8/1.8
[1] 31
> round(55.8/1.8) == (55.8/1.8)
[1] FALSE
> round(55.8/1.8) - (55.8/1.8)
[1] 3.552714e-15
```

How is it possible? Is it a bug? I found it after verifying some data in a dataset where I was looking for records where the division between two numbers was not integer, by checking if the `round` value was equal to the result of `/` operator.

Comment: [FAQ 7.31](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_82.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is because 55.8/1.8 is not exactly 31 in floating point math:

```
> format(55.8/1.8, digits=22)
[1] "30.99999999999999644729"
```

This is because the numbers you are using do not have exact floating point representations.

Comment: What about this example? round(0.11/(0.07+0.22+0.11),2). The expression evaluates to 0.27, even though the inner formula equals 0.275. And if you hand type 0.275 into the round call, you get 0.28

Comment: @YousifAl-Y The inner formula does not equal 0.275. Just like the original example, it equals approximately 0.2749999999999999666933, which rounds down to 0.27.